# Why is numpy.trapz() returning zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following setup:

```
a.T = [[0.  0.4 0.8 1.2 1.6 1.  1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 0.5 0.9 1.3 1.7 2.1 2. ]]
b.T = [[0.  0.4 0.8 1.2 1.6 2.  2.2 2.4 2.6 2.8 3.  3.4 3.8 4.2 4.6 5. ]]
```

Consider `b` as being the time values and the values taken by a function at those instants is given by `a`.

Now when I do `np.trapz(interpolated_age,interpolated_time)`, I get the result of this integral operation as multiple 0 valued arrays. But if I do the `transpose` operation to the arguments of the `trapz` method, i.e. `np.trapz(interpolated_age.T,interpolated_time.T)`, I get the correct answer as a single value.

Can someone point out what's the reason behind this? I thought for `trapz` operation, we only need 2 same sized arrays for the 2D integration.

Comment: link to the whole code - [link](https://github.com/biplavc/AgeOfInformation/blob/master/first_attempt.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your arrays `interpolated_age` and `interpolated_time` are of shape(n,1). [`trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) has an `axis` parameter with default `-1` (last axis). That means that you calculate n times the area under a single point which is `0`, hence you get an array of n zeros.

If you need your array to be 2D then specify `axis=0` to integrate over the first axis (n points) to get the correct result.

```
area_under_curve = np.trapz(interpolated_age, interpolated_time, axis=0)
```

Alternatively, you may check if you could use simple 1D arrays (can't tell from your program code).